# Magento 2: best Debuging software

Tags: magento2.4, debug, speedoptimization

I am working on speed optimization of the Magento 2 site. Does anyone know the best debugging software where I can track which magento2 PHP function takes more time?

Please share your thoughts to achieve the above approach

Comment: New Relic is free and Blackfire is commercial (they are technically different though)

Answer (score 0):

[Mage Profiler](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html)

**Perform tasks such as analyzing performance.**

**Enable profiler:-**

```
bin/magento dev:profiler:enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting blog post that might help you https://yegorshytikov.medium.com/magento-2-performance-problem-profiling-and-optimization-3a2054fe0768.

You can also try the inbuild chrome performance tool to measure how long your requests take and you can debug and see what you can improve.

And as mentioned the [Magento Profiler](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html) is also a great tool